# How do I append a specific header to an HttpResponse by default from an ASP.NET web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http-headers

I have a web service with many methods.  Clients accessing this service could be from any domain (which means I have to put some cross-domain magic in here and there).  I found a header I can add to my response that enables cross-domain ajax calls to work (this made things work for me on Chrome browser).

To solve my issue, I could just paste this:
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

on every method in my service.  That's tedious and ugly, and I was wondering if anyone knew a more elegant way of having that header in my web service response by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an embarrassingly simple solution. My web service is a class, so I just stuck the line mentioned in the question into the class constructor.